# ¿Bucle for no funciona en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

Estoy intentando hacer un simple script para la detección de puertos en Python.

```
#! /usr/bin/env pyhton3
#Se importan las librerias
import subprocess, time, os, socket
from time import sleep

#Se establecen los colores https://pypi.org/project/colored/
#https://pypi.org/project/colored/

# verde="\x1b[0;32m"
# shell="\033[0;m"


a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = input("Introduce la ip: ")

for puerto in range(1,65535):

    direccion= (ip,int(puerto))
    resultado = a_socket.connect_ex(direccion)
    print(resultado)
    if resultado == 0:
        
        print("Puerto abierto")
    else:
        print("Puerto cerrado")

    a_socket.close()
```

El problema esta en el bucle for:

Si pongo el bucle y que haga la prueba con cada puerto, del 1 al 65535 la respuesta del programa es igual a 9 y me aparece "Puerto cerrado". Hago la prueba  con `for puerto in range(1,112)' para que el numero 111 sea el penúltimo y poder ver el resultado. Respuesta:

Puerto cerrado
9
Puerto cerrado
9
Puerto cerrado

En cambio, si quito el bucle y pongo `direccion=(ip,111)` * el 111 se que está abierto, previamente comprobado en mi localhost.

[image: Puerto 111 abierto]

El script quedaría así:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env pyhton3
#Se importan las librerias
import subprocess, time, os, socket
from time import sleep

#Se establecen los colores https://pypi.org/project/colored/
#https://pypi.org/project/colored/

# verde="\x1b[0;32m"
# shell="\033[0;m"


a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = input("Introduce la ip: ")

#for puerto in range(1,112):

direccion= (ip,111)
resultado = a_socket.connect_ex(direccion)
print(resultado)
if resultado == 0:
    
    print("Puerto abierto")
else:
    print("Puerto cerrado")

a_socket.close()
```

Respuesta:

```
Introduce la ip: 127.0.0.1
0
Puerto abierto
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa es pedir que el usuario introduzca, además de la dirección IP, el puerto.

**Código**:

```
import subprocess, time, os, socket
from time import sleep

#Se establecen los colores https://pypi.org/project/colored/
#https://pypi.org/project/colored/

# verde="\x1b[0;32m"
# shell="\033[0;m"

a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = input("Introduce la IP: ")
puerto = input("Introduce el puerto: ")

direccion= (ip,int(puerto))
resultado = a_socket.connect_ex(direccion)
print(resultado)
if resultado == 0:
    print("Puerto abierto")
else:
    print("Puerto cerrado")

a_socket.close()
```

**Demo**:

Para la demostración, he usado en el móvil la aplicación WiFi File Transfer, que abre un puerto para la transferencia de archivos. Si lo activo:

```
Introduce la IP: 192.168.1.34
Introduce el puerto: 1234
0
Puerto abierto
```

Deteniendo la aplicación:

```
Introduce la IP: 192.168.1.34
Introduce el puerto: 1234
10061
Puerto cerrado
```

Comment: Va a tomar un tiempo escanear los 65535 puertos ...

Comment: He obtenido el resultado en cuestión de entre 10 y 20 segundos. ¿Cómo hacerlo más eficiente? Gracias. Solo he pedido un puerto, ¿por qué se escanean 65535 puertos?

Comment: La única manera de estar seguro es escanear el rango completo. Revisa la lista de [puertos TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Answer (score 1):

El bucle for funciona como debiera ser. Creo que te falta agregar a la impresión el número del puerto para comprobarlo.

Esto otro no tiene que ver con el for, pero no puedes re-utilizar el socket que ya has enlazada a un puerto de la forma que lo haces, lo mejor es que crees un nuevo socket en cada iteración, prueba esto:

```
import socket

ip = input("Introduce la ip: ")
for puerto in range(75,85):
    a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    direccion= (ip,int(puerto))
    resultado = a_socket.connect_ex(direccion)
    print(direccion, resultado)
    if resultado == 0:
        print("Puerto abierto")
    else:
        print("Puerto cerrado")
    a_socket.close()
```

En mi equipo, obtengo esta salida:

```
Introduce la ip: 127.0.0.1
('127.0.0.1', 75) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 76) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 77) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 78) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 79) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 80) 0
Puerto abierto
('127.0.0.1', 81) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 82) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 83) 10061
Puerto cerrado
('127.0.0.1', 84) 10061
Puerto cerrado
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Arreglado, debí poner el a_scoket=... dentro del bucle

```
#! /usr/bin/env pyhton3
```

#Se importan las librerias
import subprocess, time, os, socket
from time import sleep

#Se establecen los colores https://pypi.org/project/colored/
#https://pypi.org/project/colored/

## verde="\x1b[0;32m"

## shell="\033[0;m"

ip = input("Introduce la ip: ")

for puerto in range(1,65535):

```
a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
direccion= (ip,int(puerto))

resultado = a_socket.connect_ex(direccion)
print(resultado)
if resultado == 0:
    
    print("Puerto abierto")
else:
    print("Puerto cerrado")

a_socket.close()
```

Comment: Debes publicar el código resultante para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema se puedan guiar.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes otro método.
Gracias al socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.001)
Hará que tu escaneo de puertos vaya muchísimo mas rápido :)

```
import socket

target = "la-ip-que-quieras-escanear"


def openPorts(target):
    print(f"Escaneando puertos de: {target} IPv4 pública...")
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.001)
    for port in range(1, 65535):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = s.connect_ex((target, port))
        print(f"Puerto {port} esta abierto") if result == 0 else s.close()


openPorts(target)
```